# Deleting a File in Android returns false

Tags: android, file-io

I'm trying to delete a file in my Android app. The file was preciously created by the same Android app, and has MODE_WORLD_READABLE permissions.

I'm trying to delete it as follows:

```
File chosenFile = context.getFileStreamPath("myfile.txt");
boolean fileDeleted = chosenFile.delete();
if (fileDeleted)
  Log.d(TAG, "myfile.txt was deleted");
else
  Log.d(TAG, "myfile.txt was not deleted");
```

chosenFile.delete() keeps returning false. Is it because it's still being accessed? If so, is there any way I can force close it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I figured out my mistake - the file doesn't exist in the first place. I thought I guarded against that by checking if (chosenFile == null), but I should've checked if (chosenFile.exist() == true) instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Did you give this permission.

Comment: Yes I do. Anyway, the file should reside in the app's directory rather than external storage.

Answer (score 0):

for this line of code is **myfile.txt** exists, please check that first, file write permissions are not required for writing in private file system. Its required only when you try to write external storage.

`context.getFileStreamPath("myfile.txt");`

and to delete the file use

`context.deleteFile("myfile.txt")`;

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get what you mean. How do I check that file write permissions are not required for writing in private file system?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> i mean this

Comment: Thanks. I tried context.deleteFile() but that returned false as well. The funny thing is, sometimes chosenFile.delete() works, but I'm unable to figure out under what conditions it works.

Comment: then check your context, keep your context same always for file management

Comment: How do I check if the context is the same? I've tried creating and deleting a new file right before trying to delete the chosenFile. The deletion of the new file works just fine, but deleting chosenFile doesn't. Happens consistently.